# Easy question about closure in the multiplicative group of integers modulo m

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am currently looking at the group $M:= (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^* :=(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})\setminus m\mathbb{Z}$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo m.

**I need to show that M is closed under multiplication for $m\geq 2$ iff m is prime.**

Here we use that $ p \geq 2$ is prime iff with $p|kl$ then $p|k$ or $p|l$.

- Why is it, that if $M$ is closed under multiplication, then for $k,l \notin m\mathbb{Z}$ also $kl\notin m\mathbb{Z}$?
- Why is if $k,l \notin m\mathbb{Z}$ also $kl\notin m\mathbb{Z}$, then this means that m is prime?

My book says that the closure of M means that
$
k \notin m\mathbb{Z}$ and $ l \notin m\mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow kl\notin m\mathbb{Z}
$
and that this is equivalent to the definition of prime in the first question
$$
p|kl \Rightarrow p|l \wedge p|k
$$. I don't understand why the closure means that and why it is equivalent to the definition of prime. I can only understand the question about the closure if assumed that $k,l\in M$ but that makes no sense, because it would naturally mean that $k,l \notin m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: the second point needs clarification, because $1,3\not\in4\mathbb Z$ and $1\times3\not\in4\mathbb Z$ and yet $4$ is not prime, though $2,2\not\in4\mathbb Z$ and $2\times2\in 4\mathbb Z$

Comment: Thank you, I will clarify that. You are right.

Comment: It is essential to state your *definition* of "$(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^*$, the multiplicative group..." since that plays a key role here. Please do so in the question.

Comment: thanks @BillDubuque I did it.

Comment: So, using your definition, $\, k,l\in M\,\Rightarrow\, k,l\not\in mZ \Rightarrow\, kl\not \in m\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow kl\in M\ \ $

Comment: exactly @BillDubuque.

Comment: You don't see why $\, m\mid kl\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid k\,$ or $\,m\mid l\,$ implies $\,m\,$ is prime for $\,m>1?\ $ What if $\, m = kl\,$ is composite? Then $\,m\mid kl\,$ but ...

Comment: I think I could explain it using $G\Rightarrow H \Leftrightarrow \neg H \Rightarrow \neg G$ @BillDubuque. $k\in MZ$ means that m divides k so it could work. I will also think about your way there as it seems more formal and better.

Comment: Btw, the above inference $\, k,l\in M\,\Rightarrow\, kl\in M\,$ comes from $M$ being closed under multiplication (being a group). Rewriting it in terms of divisibility shows that it is equivalent to $m$ being prime (for $m>1)$ - to be sure you have the logic correct, i.e. the leftmost and rightmost arrows in my first comment should be $\iff$ since they are *by definition*.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks a lot

Comment: You can answer your own question if you see it now (which is a good way to get feedback on its correctness).